# Data model for subscriptions, single purchase products and variable services

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am designing a database for a system that will handle subscription based products, standard one off set price purchase products, and billing of variable services.

A customer can be related to many domains and a domain may have many subscriptions, set priced products or billed variable services related to it.

I am unsure whether to seperate each of these categories into their own 'orders' table or figure out a solution to compile them all into a single orders table.

Certain information about subscriptions is required such as start date or expiry date which is irrelevant for stand alone products. Variable services could be any price so having a single products table would mean I would have to add a new product which may be never used again or might be at a different cost.

What would be the best way to tackle this, and is splitting each into seperate order tables the best way?

Comment: What is the "best" data model is a subjective question that's not really possible to answer without more details about what your system is supposed to do. For example, at what interval are subscriptions billed? Are all subscriptions billed the same way? And what are the differences between "one-off set price products" and "variable services"? What other data elements are orders related to? Etc. Showing what your current model looks like might answer a lot of these questions.

Comment: I think _make a database design from a 10 line description_ does not work for a real application. Otherwise consultants would have nothing to do.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at sub-typing - it might work for you. By this I mean a central "order" table containing the common attributes and optional "is a"/one-to-one relationships to specific order tables. The specific order tables contain the attributes specific only to that type of order, and a foreign key back to the central order table.

This is one way of trying to get the best of "both" worlds, by which I mean (a) the appropriate level of centralisation for reporting on things common and (b) the right level of specialisation. The added nuance comes at the cost of an extra join some times but gives you flexibility and reporting.

Although I am a little biased in favour of subtypes, some people feel that unless your order subtypes are very different, it may not be worth the effort of separating them out. There is some seemingly good discussion [here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16543/supertype-subtype-deciding-between-category-complete-disjoint-or-incomplete-ove) as well as [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54263/relationships-between-subtypes-of-an-entity/54424#54424). That being said, books (or chapters at least) have been written on the subject!

Answer (score 0):

As with any data model, the "best" way depends on your needs. Since you don't specify a lot of details regarding your specific needs, it's difficult to say what the bets model is.

However, in general you need to consider what level of detail is necessary. For example if all subscriptions cost the same and are billed on the 1st of the month, it may be sufficient to have a field like `is_subscription ENUM ('Y', 'N')` in your orders table. If billing dates and prices for subscriptions can vary however, you need to store that information too. In that case it may be better to have a separate table for subscriptions.

Another consideration is exactly what an "order" represents in your model. One interpretation is that an order includes all the purchases included in one *transaction*, including both one-off purchases, variable services and subscriptions. A completed order would then result in a *bill*, and subscriptions would be automatically billed on the proper day of the month without a new order being made.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to have one database design that is not hardwired into specifics regarding its contents, and if it does (have to) it does in such a way that it seperates the specialization from the core DB design.

There are certain fields that are common for each order. Put these in one table, and have it refer to the other rows in the respective (specialized) tables. Thats DB normalization for you.

You could have main table contain `ID, OrderID, ItemType, ItemID` when `ItemType` determines the table `ItemID` refers to. I advise against this, but must admit that i use this sometimes.

Better would be to have these tables:

```
Clients:     ID, Name, Address, Phone
Sellers:     ID, Name, CompanyAlias

Orders:      ID, ClientID, SellerID, Date, Price
OrderItems:  ID, OrderID, DiscountAmount, DiscountPercentage,
                 ProductDomainID, ProductBottleID, ProductCheeseID, ..
```

Now `OrderItems` is where the magic happens. The first four fields explain themselves i guess. And the rest refers to a table which you do not alter or delete anything ever:

```
Products_Cheese   ID, ProductCode, ProductName, Price
```

And if you do need a variant product for a specific order add a field `VariantOfID` thats otherwise NULL. Then refer to that ID.

The `OrderItems` table you can add fields to without disturbing the established DB structure. Just constrict yourself to use `NULL` values in all `Product*ID` fields except one. But taking this further, you might even have scenario's where you want to combine two or more fields. For example adding a `ExtraSubscriptionTimespanID` or a `ExtraServicelevelagreementID` field that is set alongside the `ProductCheeseID`.

---

This way if you use `ProductCheeseID` + `ExtraSubscriptionTimespanID` + `ExtraServicelevelagreementID` a customer can order a **Cheese subscription with SLA**, and your database structure does not repeat itself.

This basic design is open to alterative ideas and solutions. But keep your structure seperated. Dont make one huge table that includes all fields you may ever need, things will break horribly once you have to change something later on.

Answer (score 0):

When designing database tables, you want to focus on what an entity represents and having two or more slightly different versions of what is essentially the same entity makes the schema harder to maintain. Orders are orders, they're just different order types for different products, for different customers. You'd need a number of link tables to make it all work, but you'd have to make those associations somehow and it beats having different entity types. How about this for a very rough starting point?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to tackle this, and is splitting each into seperate order tables the best way?

That depends. And it will change over time. So the crucial part here is that you create a model of the orders and you separate the storage of them from just writing code dealing with those models.

That done, you can develop and change the database structure over time to store and query all the information you need to store and you need to query.

This for the general advice.

More concrete you still have to map the model onto a data-structure. There are many ways on how to solve that, e.g. a single table of which not all columns are used all the time (flat table), subtype tables (for each type a new table is used) or main table with the common fields and subtype tables containing the additional columns or even attribute tables. All these approaches have pros and cons, an answer here on Stackoverflow is most likely the wrong place to discuss these in full. However, you can find an insightful entry-level discussion of your problem here:

> *Entity-Attribute-Value* (Chapter 6); page 61 in *SQL Antipatterns - Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming* by *Bill Karwin*.